# Non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1

Tags: libav

I have an error with 1gb videofile and avconv

```
Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing 
dts to muxer in stream 1: 177873 >= 177849
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

I use

```
avconv -i /root/video/112-1.wmv -y -strict experimental -b:v 1800K -ss 00:00:10 -c:v libx264  -c:a libfaac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 128k -threads 0 -maxrate 1850k -bufsize 1000k -vf "scale=w=1280:h=720, drawtext=fontfile=FreeSans.ttf:text='site.com':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=20:x=1130:y=695" /root/converted/112-1.wmv
```

Here is my log http://pastebin.com/BwBmVMDs

I tried to suppress b-frames by adding `-bf 0` option, but also same error.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: I have similar issues working with .wmv input and avconv. For what it's worth, Stream 1 appears to be the audio stream on my system. I'm just trying to pull an audio track from a .wmv for alignment purposes. It appears I have the same issue but with `-c:a libmp3lame`  as oppsed to `-c:a libfaac`